# boost::asio::async_read ends without fulfilling the completion condition

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio

On Windows, I am observing that if an `async_read` operation successfully completes on a serial port, and I immediately initiate another `async_read` operation to read `n` bytes, the second `async_read` operation immediately completes unexpectedly with success and 0 bytes transferred.

- after the second `async_read` operation, if a third `async_read` operation is initiated to read `n` bytes, then it will complete with success and `n` bytes transferred

  ```cpp
  // where buffer_size(buffer) and n are both greater than 1
  async_read(serial, buffer, transfer_exactly(n), [](error, bytes_transferred) {
    // completes with error=success and bytes_transferred=n
    async_read(serial, buffer, transfer_exactly(n), [](error, bytes_transferred) {
      // complete with error=success and bytes_transferred=0
      async_read(serial, buffer, transfer_exactly(n), [](error, bytes_transferred) {
        // completes with error=success and bytes_transferred=n
      });
    });
  });
  ```
- if a 1 millisecond sleep is performed between the first and second `async_read` operation, then the second operation will complete with success and `n` bytes transferred

  ```cpp
  // where buffer_size(buffer) and n are both greater than 1
  async_read(serial, buffer, transfer_exactly(n), [](error, bytes_transferred) {
    // completes with error=success and bytes_transferred=n
    sleep_for(milliseconds(1));
    async_read(serial, buffer, transfer_exactly(n), [](error, bytes_transferred) {
      // completes with error=success and bytes_transferred=n
    });
  });
  ```

Why is this happening and how can I avoid it?

---

For specifics, I am using Boost.Asio on Windows to communicate with a micro-controller via RS232 emulated by an ATXMEGA-192A3U.  I send a start command to the controller and read the output with a timeout. I read the output by calling the `ReadPort` function for which the code is given below.  The program performs the following reading tasks in a row:

1. Check the answer of the micro-controller to the start command.  This read succeeds in reading the 3 characters I expect: `R\r\n`
2. Read `n` bytes of output from the controller for a few hundreds of ms.

The `async_read` operation in step 2 unexpectedly completes with success, despite not having read the number of requested bytes.

```cpp
class BoostBasedCommunication
{
public:
    BoostBasedCommunication();
    ~BoostBasedCommunication(void);
    /*...*/
    virtual int ReadPort(
        int const numberOfCharacters, // maximum number of characters to be read
        unsigned long const globalTimeout, // maximum time the operation is allowed to take in ms
        unsigned long const intermediateTimeout, // maximum time allowed between two consequtive characters in ms
        int& numberOfCharactersRead
        );
    /*...*/

private:
    /*...*/
    std::vector<unsigned char> inputBuffer; ///< buffer to save data to that is received
    size_t numberOfBytesRead; ///< Number of bytes read
    int lastErrorCode; ///< last error code
    io_service my_io_service; ///< boost io service class
    serial_port port; ///< boost serial port class
    /*...*/
};

// Reads from the port until numberOfCharacters have been read, or the 
// deadline_timer has expired, or the time between two consecutive calls of 
// the completion condition is larger than intermediateTimeoutMS

int BoostBasedCommunication::ReadPort(
    int const numberOfCharacters, // maximum number of characters to be read
    unsigned long const globalTimeoutMS, // maximum time the operation is allowed to take in ms
    unsigned long const intermediateTimeoutMS, // maximum time allowed between two consecutive characters in ms
    int& numberOfCharactersRead // Actual number of characters read
    )
{
    try
    {
        OutputDebugStringA("ReadPort called\r\n");
        my_io_service.reset();
        deadline_timer gloabalTimeout(my_io_service);
        inputBuffer.resize(numberOfCharacters);
        timeoutHandler myGlobalTimeoutHandler(&port);

        completion_handler_2 myHandler(&gloabalTimeout, numberOfBytesRead);
        completion_condition_2 my_completion_condition(intermediateTimeoutMS, numberOfCharacters);

        // Set the timer
        gloabalTimeout.expires_from_now(boost::posix_time::milliseconds(globalTimeoutMS));
        gloabalTimeout.async_wait(myGlobalTimeoutHandler);

        async_read(port, boost::asio::buffer(inputBuffer, numberOfCharacters), my_completion_condition, myHandler);

        my_io_service.run(); // run the io service
        numberOfCharactersRead = numberOfBytesRead;
    }
    catch (std::exception&)
    {
        return COMMUNICATIONFAILED;
    }
    return NOERROR;
}

class completion_condition_2
{
public:
    completion_condition_2(
        long intermediateTimeOutTime,
        size_t numberOfCharactersTobeRead
        ) :intermediateTimeOutTime(intermediateTimeOutTime),
        numberOfCharactersTobeRead(numberOfCharactersTobeRead)
    {}

    std::size_t operator()(
        const boost::system::error_code& error, // Result of latest async_read_some operation.
        std::size_t bytes_transferred // Number of bytes transferred so far.
        )
    {
        if (error)
        {
            OutputDebugStringA(("completion_condition received error code: " + error.message() + "\r\n").c_str());

            if (error.value() == ERROR_OPERATION_ABORTED)
            {
                return 0;
            }
        }

        /* ...Code concerning the intermediate timeout, which is commented out...*/

        if (numberOfCharactersTobeRead <= bytes_transferred) // Enough data has been read
        {
            std::stringstream message;
            message << "completion_condition: bytes transferred: " << bytes_transferred << " of " << numberOfCharactersTobeRead << " => done!" << std::endl;
            OutputDebugStringA(message.str().c_str());
            return 0;
        }
        else // More data should be read.
        {
            std::stringstream message;
            message << "completion_condition: bytes transferred: " << bytes_transferred << " of " << numberOfCharactersTobeRead << " => continue!" << std::endl;
            OutputDebugStringA(message.str().c_str());
            return numberOfCharactersTobeRead - bytes_transferred;
        }
    }

private:
    size_t numberOfCharactersTobeRead; ///< Number of characters to be read
};

class completion_handler_2 {
public:
    completion_handler_2(
        deadline_timer* _globalTimeout,
        size_t& numberOfBytesRead
        ) :_globalTimeout(_globalTimeout),
        numberOfBytesRead(numberOfBytesRead)
    {
    }

    void operator()(
        const boost::system::error_code& error, // Result of operation.
        std::size_t bytes_transferred           // Number of bytes read.
        )
    {
        OutputDebugStringA(("completion handler called with error code: " + error.message() + "\r\n").c_str());
        if (error)
        {
            if (error.value() == ERROR_OPERATION_ABORTED)
            {
                numberOfBytesRead = bytes_transferred;
                return;
            }
            else
            {
                BOOST_THROW_EXCEPTION(std::exception("Communication failed"));
            }
        }

        OutputDebugStringA("completion handler: timeout cancelation.\r\n");

        _globalTimeout->cancel();
        numberOfBytesRead = bytes_transferred;
    }

private:
    deadline_timer* _globalTimeout; ///< global timeout deadline timer
    size_t& numberOfBytesRead; ///< number of bytes read
};
```

When I perform the first read that is working as expected, I receive the following output:

```
ReadPort called
completion_condition: bytes transferred: 0 of 3 => continue!
completion_condition: bytes transferred: 3 of 3 => done!
completion handler called with error code: success
completion handler timeout cancelation.
timeoutHandler received error code: The I/O operation has been aborted because of either a thread exit or an application request
```

If I immediately perform another read after the first has completed, the operation completes after 2 ms with the following output:

```
ReadPort called
completion_condition: bytes transferred: 0 of 1024 => continue!
completion handler called with error code: success // Why is the completion handler called here, although the completion condition did not return 0?
completion handler timeout cancelation.
timeoutHandler received error code: The I/O operation has been aborted because of either a thread exit or an application request
```

A third read, immediately following the last one works as expected:

```
ReadPort called
completion_condition: bytes transferred: 0 of 1024 => continue!
completion_condition: bytes transferred: 8 of 1024 => continue!
...
completion_condition: bytes transferred: 88 of 1024 => continue!
completion_condition: bytes transferred: 96 of 1024 => continue!
timeoutHandler called cancel of seriel port.
completion_condition received error code: The I/O operation has been aborted because of either a thread exit or an application request
completion handler called with error code: The I/O operation has been aborted because of either a thread exit or an application request
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short, the fundamental problem is either:

- Asio's interpretation of the `ReadFile` API contract with timeouts is incorrect
- a communication driver is violating the `ReadFile` API contract

The easiest solution is to account for this behavior in the application code, and issue another `async_read` operation if the prior one completes with success and 0 bytes read.  Depending on the communication driver's implementation, a 1 milliseconds sleep between reads *may* work.

---

The [`COMMTIMEOUTS`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363190(v=vs.85).aspx) documentation states that for the read interval timeout:

> The maximum time allowed to elapse before the arrival of the **next byte** on the communications line, in milliseconds. If the **interval between the arrival of any two bytes** exceeds this amount, the `ReadFile` operation is completed and any buffered data is returned. [...]

Asio's interpretation of the documentation, namely the emphasized text, is that for a *given* [`ReadFile`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365467(v=vs.85).aspx) operation, the read interval timeout begins *after* the first byte has been read.  The implication is that if `ReadFile` is requested to read more than 0 bytes, Asio does not expect the `ReadFile` operation to return a status indicating it has successfully read 0 bytes synchronously or asynchronously.  With this interpretation, Asio's [implementation](https://github.com/boostorg/asio/blob/boost-1.60.0/include/boost/asio/detail/impl/win_iocp_serial_port_service.ipp#L100) configures the serial port with a read interval timeout of 1 millisecond<sup>1</sup>.

```cpp
// Set up timeouts so that the serial port will behave similarly to a
// network socket. Reads wait for at least one byte, then return with
// whatever they have. Writes return once everything is out the door.
::COMMTIMEOUTS timeouts;
timeouts.ReadIntervalTimeout = 1;
timeouts.ReadTotalTimeoutMultiplier = 0;
timeouts.ReadTotalTimeoutConstant = 0;
```

The [`async_read`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/async_read/overload2.html) is a composed operation implemented in zero or more calls to intermediate `async_read_some` operations.  The `async_read` operation interprets an intermediate `async_read_some` operation completing with success and 0 bytes transferred as-if no further progress will be made for the composed operation, and thus the `async_read` operation completes.  This interpretation becomes problematic when the underlying system call to `ReadFile` unexpectedly completes synchronously with success and 0 bytes read.

With this details, alternative solutions are to either:

- patch the communication driver so that a timeout interval only begins for a `ReadFile` operation once the operation has read at least a single byte
- patch Asio.  If one has detailed the observed behavior of `ReadFile` and finds that it only occurs if the `ReadFile` operation completes synchronously, then one may be able to patch the `async_read_some()` operation within [`win_iocp_handle_service::start_read_op`](https://github.com/boostorg/asio/blob/boost-1.60.0/include/boost/asio/detail/impl/win_iocp_handle_service.ipp#L481).  Otherwise, one could patch the various `read_op` specializations so that their [completion predicate](https://github.com/boostorg/asio/blob/boost-1.60.0/include/boost/asio/impl/read.hpp#L276) does not exit if 0 bytes have been read, but more than 0 had been requested.

---

<sub>1. If the communication driver's implementation is allowing the read interval timeout that started at the last byte read for `ReadFilen` operation to affect `ReadFilen+1` operation that is initiated within the read interval timeout gap, then sleeping between `ReadFilen` and `ReadFilen+1` for the period of the read interval timeout would prevent the Asio read operations from completing with success and 0 bytes when the supplied buffer's size is greater than 0 bytes.</sub>

Comment: With this in mind, I was able to establish a stable communication between the computer and the micro-controller.

However, I think I do not understand the effect of the 1 ms timeout. The micro-controller at some points acts as a talker, which outputs 8 bytes about every 7.5 ms. I can read the port for several 100 ms without hitting a timeout. Why isn't the communication aborting after the first 8 bytes, although it takes more than 1 ms until the next 8 bytes arrive?

Comment: @PaulR. `ReadFile` is timing out after 8 bytes due to its 1 ms read interval timeout configuration.  Note how in your output, when attempting to read 1024 bytes with the `async_read` composed operation, each intermediate `async_read_some` operation reads 8 bytes.

Comment: ok, I understand. So after the 8 bytes, my completion condition callback is called, which is what I observe.